# Symfony2 Logout with remember me

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have successfully got Symfony authentication working with remember me. But when it comes to logging out, the remember cookies appear to be preventing the user from actually logging out.

My security.yml config

```
default:
  anonymous: ~
  http_basic: ~
  form_login:
    login_path:           login
    check_path:           login-check
    default_target_path:  dashboard
    username_parameter:   email
    password_parameter:   password
  logout:
    path:                 /logout
    target:               login
  remember_me:
    key:                  "%secret%"
    always_remember_me:   true
```

I found `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\CookieClearingLogoutHandler` but it appears the method `logout` in this is never called.

Is there some additional configuration needed?